# MySQL 8 MEMBER OF does not work against empty JSON arrays

Tags: mysql

So if you're not familiar, `MEMBER OF` instead of `JSON_CONTAINS` in MySQL is *significantly* faster by a huge magnitude due to that `MEMBER OF` does not parse the JSON whereas `JSON_CONTAINS` does.

When dealing with millions of rows, JSON_CONTAINS is simply not an option, however, I believe I've discovered a flaw that where if the JSON array is empty it will incorrectly return no results

Let's say `mytable` contains a JSON column called `tags` with a row where this column is simply a `JSON_ARRAY()` (`[]`) the below will not work despite `Easy` not being within the array.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    NOT 'Easy' MEMBER OF (tags -> '$[*]')
```

Am I missing something here or is the only solution to:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `mytable`
WHERE
    tags = JSON_ARRAY()
    OR NOT 'Easy' MEMBER OF (tags -> '$[*]')
```

This seems like a significant oversight?

`Easy` is not a member of `[]` so it should return records that have empty tags.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/j37uH2Im Please add sample data and result of select version()

Comment: Thanks, it's the `-> '$[*]'` thats causing it to ignore empty JSON arrays

Comment: Why use `->'$[*]'`. Anyway, it sounds like a bug that you should report to MySQL.

Comment: json_extract (-.) 'Returns NULL if any argument is NULL or no paths locate a value in the document' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html , so not a bug and the test for null is is null , so the member of behaviour differs when json_extract occurs.